# Ну никак не работает

Tags: tampermonkey

Прошу помощи у спецов.
Есть код :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("_2thnNx-xCf3inVP2jkK276")[0].textContent);
```

В консоли в браузере срабатывает. Т.е. выдает искомое значение.

Использую его в Tampermonkey не идет, пишет:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at Si (userscript.html?name=New%20Userscript.user.js&id=b1c43f14-0bd8-4ecc-8874-876b76ed2b71:21)
```

Comment: И вот еще в чем сложность. Которая и является проблемой. 
Вхожу на сайт, жду полной загрузки, из буфера вставляю свой код 
`document.getElementsByClassName("_2thnNx-xCf3inVP2jkK276")[0].textContent`
Вначале выдает ошибку. 
Далее на странице повторно делаю "Просмотреть код страницы"
Копию тот же самый элемент span 
(Т.е. он у меня уже как бы скопирован в буфер и я его до этого вставил вместе с кодом) но он не срабатывает. 

Получается код срабатывает только после того, как я повторно вставлю имя искомого span класса

Comment: В общем код даже в консоле срабатывает после того как я нажму в браузере "Просмотреть код" ????

Answer (score 1):

Просто класс, который вы ищете, еще не не подгружен. Дождитесь пока документ полностью загрузится. Например:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    myFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Дополните свой ответ – например, рабочим кодом или ссылками на документацию.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.
Самое интересное то, что я так тоже думал. 
Поставил задежку. И все так же

Comment: В Ваш код добавил еще дополнительную задержку. 
Т.е. он теперь как Вы написали ждет загрузки станицы + выжидает 50 секунд. 

Но ситуация такая же.

Comment: Так посмотрите, находятся ли отцовские элементы, чудес же не бывает. Покажите код, как вы это сделали.

Comment: `(function() {

    use 'strict'

  document.onreadystatechange = function () {

  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {

    function Si() {

        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("_2thnNx-xCf3inVP2jkK276")[0].textContent);

         }

 setInterval(Si,50 * 1000);

  }

}`